# Failure in make fails to halt shell script

Tags: shell, makefile, cmake, sh

I am automating the building and unit testing of a [personal project](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/master/VMWithEditor/UnitTests) using bash scripts (parts of the unit testing have been [reviewed on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248559/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-a)), cmake and make on the latest version of Fedora Linux. The postive test passes on on the build system, however, when I force an LD failure in one of the unit tests the build still passes at the higher levels. It needs to fail at all levels.

Here is the error message from the make generated by a cmake command:

```
/home/pacman/Documents/projects/VMWithEditor/VMWithEditor/human_readable_program_format.c:179: multiple definition of `HRF_delete_linked_list_of_program_steps'; CMakeFiles/Run_All_Unit_Tests.exe.dir/home/pacman/Documents/projects/VMWithEditor/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/HRF_UnitTest/HRF_UnitTest/unit_test_human_readable_program_format.c.o:/home/pacman/Documents/projects/VMWithEditor/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/../../../human_readable_program_format.c:179: first defined here  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Run_All_Unit_Tests.exe.dir/build.make:433: Run_All_Unit_Tests.exe] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pacman/Documents/projects/VMWithEditor/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/Debug'  
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/Run_All_Unit_Tests.exe.dir/all] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pacman/Documents/projects/VMWithEditor/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/Debug'  
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

This is the output of the top level shell script, the last 2 builds should not execute:

```
Building CommandLine_UnitTest/CommandLine_UnitTest  
Building ControlConsole_UnitTest/ControlConsole_UnitTest  
Building Editor_UnitTest/Editor_UnitTest  
Building HRF_UnitTest/HRF_UnitTest  
Building Parser_Unit_Test/Parser_Unit_Test  
Building RunAllUnitTests/RunAllUnitTests  
Building State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test  
Building VirtualMachine_UnitTest/VirtualMachine_UnitTest
```

This is the shell script that doesn't fail when it should:

### buildDebug.sh

```
#! /bin/sh

# Create a Debug build directory and then build the target within the Debug directory
# Stop on any build errors and stop the parent process.

mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "\n\ncmake failed $retval!\n\n"
    exit $retVal
fi
make VERBOSE=1
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "\n\nmake failed! $retval\n\n"
    exit $retVal
fi
```

The previous shell script is called by this shell script, there are 8 instances of the previous shell script in subdirectories.

### buildAllDebug.sh

```
#! /bin/sh

# Build the debug version of all the unit tests
# Stop on any build errors.

for i in *
do
    if [ -d $i ] ; then
        TESTDIRECTORY="$i/$i"
        SHELLFILE="$TESTDIRECTORY/buildDebug.sh";
        if [ -f $SHELLFILE ] ; then
            echo "Building $TESTDIRECTORY";
            cd "$TESTDIRECTORY"
            ./buildDebug.sh >& buildDebuglog.txt
            retVal=$?
            if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
                exit $retVal
            fi
            cd ../..
        fi
    fi
done;
```

This generates the make file that is reporting the error:

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.4)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "Run_All_Unit_Tests.exe")

project(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} LANGUAGES C VERSION 1.0)

if("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(GCC_WARN_COMPILE_FLAGS  " -Wall ")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_WARN_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif()

set(VM_SRC_DIR "../../..")
set(COMMON_TEST_DIR "../../Common_UnitTest_Code")
set(LEXICAL_TEST_DIR "../../State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test")
set(PARSER_TEST_DIR "../../Parser_Unit_Test/Parser_Unit_Test")
set(CMD_LINE_TEST_DIR "../../CommandLine_UnitTest/CommandLine_UnitTest")
set(HRF_TEST_DIR "../../HRF_UnitTest/HRF_UnitTest")


add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
run_all_unit_tests_main.c
${HRF_TEST_DIR}/hrf_unit_test_main.c
${HRF_TEST_DIR}/unit_test_human_readable_program_format.c
${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}/lexical_analyzer_unit_test_main.c 
${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}/internal_character_transition_unit_tests.c
${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}/internal_sytax_state_tests.c
${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}/lexical_analyzer_test_data.c
${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}/lexical_analyzer_unit_test_utilities.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/error_reporting.c  
${VM_SRC_DIR}/safe_string_functions.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/arg_flags.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/file_io_vm.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/opcode.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/parser.c 
${VM_SRC_DIR}/default_program.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/human_readable_program_format.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/lexical_analyzer.c 
${VM_SRC_DIR}/virtual_machine.c 
${PARSER_TEST_DIR}/parser_unit_test_main.c
${PARSER_TEST_DIR}/internal_parser_tests.c
${PARSER_TEST_DIR}/parser_unit_test.c
${CMD_LINE_TEST_DIR}/command_line_unit_test_main.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/error_reporting.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/arg_flags.c
${VM_SRC_DIR}/safe_string_functions.c
${COMMON_TEST_DIR}/unit_test_logging.c
)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

configure_file(VMWithEditorConfig.h.in VMWithEditorConfig.h)

target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC UNIT_TESTING)
target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC ALL_UNIT_TESTING)
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${VM_SRC_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${COMMON_TEST_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${LEXICAL_TEST_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${CMD_LINE_TEST_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${PARSER_TEST_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE "${HRF_TEST_DIR}")
```

### The Directory Stucture for the builds:

This was generated by ls -R and then edited to remove what isn't necessary for this question.

```
/UnitTests/:
    buildAllDebug.sh  
    buildAll.log  
    buildDebug.sh  
    buildRelease.sh  
    CommandLine_UnitTest  
    Common_UnitTest_Code  
    ControlConsole_UnitTest
    DirStructure.txt
    Editor_UnitTest
    HRF_UnitTest
    Parser_Unit_Test
    RunAllUnitTests
    State_Machine_Unit_Test
    UnitTests
    VirtualMachine_UnitTest

    /UnitTests/CommandLine_UnitTest:
    /UnitTests/CommandLine_UnitTest/CommandLine_UnitTest:
    buildDebuglog.txt
    buildDebug.sh
    buildRelease.sh
    CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/Common_UnitTest_Code:

    /UnitTests/ControlConsole_UnitTest:
    /UnitTests/ControlConsole_UnitTest/ControlConsole_UnitTest:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/Editor_UnitTest:
    /UnitTests/Editor_UnitTest/Editor_UnitTest:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/HRF_UnitTest:
    /UnitTests/HRF_UnitTest/HRF_UnitTest:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/Parser_Unit_Test:
    /UnitTests/Parser_Unit_Test/Parser_Unit_Test:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/RunAllUnitTests:
    /UnitTests/RunAllUnitTests/RunAllUnitTests:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test:
    /UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt

    /UnitTests/UnitTests:

    /UnitTests/VirtualMachine_UnitTest:
    /UnitTests/VirtualMachine_UnitTest/VirtualMachine_UnitTest:
        buildDebug.sh
        buildRelease.sh
        CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, so that should be #! /usr/bin/bash instead?

Comment: I suggest to replace `bash` tag with `sh` tag.

Comment: @Cyrus : What's the point in switching to bash? On the first glance, the script seems to be POSIX shell anyway.

Comment: @user1934428: I did not suggest to change from `sh` to `bash` but to change the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have:

```
make VERBOSE=1
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
```

but `retVal` is still the return code of the `cmake` command.  Either reset it or test `$?` directly.